# retrieve data from SQLite with multiple records

Tags: ios, cocoa, sqlite

was wondering if anyone could share how to retrieve data from SQLite with multiple records, i.e I have a table with 5 fields each has multiple data.

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ etc...", oneString,two...];

[entry addObject:str];
```

I get only the first record

One more thing the below string works

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM abc"];
```

but this one doesn't, I get a crash!

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM abc WHERE name= \"john\""];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)readInformationFromDatabase
{
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Setup the database object
sqlite3 *database;

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access

    //SQLIte Statement 
    NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from TableName"];

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            // Init the Data Dictionary 
            NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            NSString *_userName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
           // NSLog(@"_userName = %@",_userName);

            NSString *_emailID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
           // NSLog(@"_emailID = %@",_emailID);

            NSString *_contactNumber = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
           // NSLog(@"_contactNumber = %@",_contactNumber);

            NSString *_address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
           // NSLog(@"_address = %@",_address);

            NSString *_zipCode = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
           // NSLog(@"_zipCode = %@",_zipCode);

            [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_userName] forKey:@"UserName"];
            [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_emailID] forKey:@"EmailId"];
            [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_contactNumber] forKey:@"ContactNumber"];
            [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_address] forKey:@"Address"];
            [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_zipCode] forKey:@"ZIPCode"];

            [array addObject:_dataDictionary]; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No Data Found");
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}

sqlite3_close(database);

return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as below :

/*================================================================

            METHOD FOR Fetching Data FROM DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getData:(NSString *)query
{


//NSLog(@"QUERY : %@",query);

NSString *idToReturn=@"";
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray new];
if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *temp= [NSMutableDictionary new];
            const char *s;



            s=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0); // Here 0 is the first column index 
            if(s==NULL)
            {
                idToReturn=@"";
            }
            else
            {
                idToReturn =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
            }
            [temp setObject:idToReturn forKey:@"firstData"];

            s=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            if(s==NULL)
            {
                idToReturn=@"";
            }
            else
            {
                idToReturn =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
            }
            [temp setObject:idToReturn forKey:@"secondData"];

            s=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
            if(s==NULL)
            {
                idToReturn=@"";
            }
            else
            {
                idToReturn =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
            }
            [temp setObject:idToReturn forKey:@"thirdData"];

            s=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
            if(s==NULL)
            {
                idToReturn=@"";
            }
            else
            {
                idToReturn =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
            }
            [temp setObject:idToReturn forKey:@"forthData"];

            s=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);
            if(s==NULL)
            {
                idToReturn=@"";
            }
            else
            {
                idToReturn =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
            }
            [temp setObject:idToReturn forKey:@"fifthData"];

            if (temp != nil)
            {
                [returnArray addObject:temp];

                temp = nil;
            }

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
return returnArray;
```

}

Then call this as :

```
NSString *query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from tablename"];
NSMutableArray *data = [self getData:query];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I know which record am I at the moment? also if I have 100 records how can I seek to that specific row. 

would anyone know whats wrong with the below sqlite command?
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM abc WHERE name= \"john\""]

it crashes when I execute it.

thanks again for the help.

Comment: Hi Nishant, not sure if the forum allows to contact you privately?  if yes I appropriate your email, I would like to ask and offer. thanks.